# Where do I find my youtube v3 data API quota limit?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

on this page (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) google says:

> You can find the quota available to your application in the Developers Console.

I went to my Developer Console, and it shows me how many *requests* I made, but it does not show my exact quota (for my free account). Does anybody know how to access this information? The url for the developer console is https://console.developers.google.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Navigate to your [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
- Under "APIs & Services" (default page) click on the API you're looking for
- Click "Quotas" in the left hand side bar

This will give you a generalized view of your usage over time for that particular API.

---

Update for July 2020

Check out the [IAM Admin/Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) page for a simplified view of your usage against your total quotas.

You can change your project in the left of the top bar and search per API with the dropdown options on the page.

Clicking any of the listed quotas will show you additional metrics, e.g. a graph of requests over time.

Comment: There it is. Thank you!

Comment: it's wrong developer console! the right one https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: Updated links and provided new helpful page for seeing quota limits at a glance

Answer (score 8):

**For server/web-based apps**

The valid steps as of February 21, 2021:

- Go to **Console**: https://console.developers.google.com/ & check if correct project is selected*
- Click on the **Library** option on the left menu
- Click on the **YouTube Data API 3** option
- Click on the **Manage** button on the Youtube Data API 3 page
- Then click on **Quotas** on the left menu on the Manage page

Lastly, expand the **Queries** section to see the quota usage.

---

*Make sure the project/service is selected which is using the YouTube API

[image]

Comment: Very helpful. Only caveat is it doesn't seem to roll up your total # of queries for the given day. You can only see 5min sums over time. EDIT: Managed to find a useful link. Posting as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

go to :

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=your_app_name
```

where the **your_app_name** is your lowcased youtube api application's name.

Click  at top left's three lined menu icon.
In to-right slided menu hover/click the IAM&Admin list item and in an another list you will see that **'quota'**!